# Create bash script with menu of choices that come from the output of another script

Tags: bash, menu

forgive me if this is painfully simple but I'm not a programmer so it's hard for me to tell what's easy and what's hard.

I have a bash script that I use (that someone else wrote) for finding out internal customer data where I basically run "info customername" and it searches our internal customer database for all customer records matching that customer name and outputs a list with their account numbers (which all have the same prefix of 11111xxxxxxxx), in the form of "Sample Customer - 111119382818873".

We have another bash script where you enter "extrainfo 11111xxxxxxxx", we get the plaintext data from their account, which we use for many things that are important to us.

The missing feature is that "extrainfo" cannot search by name, only number. So I'd like to bridge that gap. Ideally, I'd enter "extrainfo customername" and it would run a search using "info customername", generate a list of results as a menu, allow me to choose which customer I meant, and then run the "extrainfo 11111xxxxxxxxx" command of that customer. If there is only one match, it would automatically run the extrainfo command properly.

Here's what I have that works but only for the first result that "info customername" generates:

```
#!/bin/bash
key=`/usr/local/bin/info $1 | grep 11111 | awk '{print $NF}'`
/usr/local/bin/extrainfo $key
```

It's the menu stuff I'm having a hard time figuring out. I hope this was clear but again, I'm pretty dumb with this stuff so I probably left something important out. Thanks.

Comment: Why not change the `extrainfo` script to accept either a name *or* an account number?

Comment: There would still need to be the menu of choices, so it's essentially the same problem. For example, we have customers with similar names, so we want to be able to type "info new york" and get a list of all customers that start with New York. My sample script works but only for the first result of that list. So we need some way to choose the proper customer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the prompt for the select command
PS3="Type a number or 'q' to quit: "

# Create a list of customer names and numbers (fill gaps with underscores)
keys=$(/usr/local/bin/info $1 | sed 's/ /_/g')

# Show a menu and ask for input.
select key in $keys; do
    if [ -n "$key" ]; then
        /usr/local/bin/extrainfo $(sed 's/.*_11111/11111/' <<<"$key")
    fi
    break
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help!

Got the following errors:
line 12: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @jasonpowell There's a missing single quote at the end of the second `sed` statement. Should be `$(sed 's/.*_11111/11111/' <<<"$key")`

Comment: Went a different route and got it working. The suggested script never got rid of the stuff before the "11111xxxx" customer number.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this script reads all the customer info, finds all lines with the customer number prefix, and loads it into search.txt. Then it displays the file with line numbers in front of it, waits for you to choose a line number, and then strips out the customer name and spaces in front of the customer id. Finally, it runs my other script with just the customer id. It's hacky but functional.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/info $1 | grep 11111 > search.txt
cat -n search.txt
read num
key=`sed -n ${num}p search.txt | awk '{print $NF}'`
/usr/local/bin/extrainfo $key
```